# Get data from HXR with python from forbidden ajax function

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web

I'm trying to request this web page https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/ranking but the HTML that returns is different than the one that I inspect. So I saw a almost similar question here about that and the answer was that you should look at the XHR that return, so I did it, and got nothing.

Here is the image of dev tools about the function "get_ranking" that I'm trying to get data.

[image]

Appreciate for the help.

Comment: The link you posted is for an HTML page. `get-ranking` is an API.

Comment: The URL is `https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking`, but apparently you will also need some sort of authorization credentials, most likely sent via cookie.

Comment: Yeah, you both are right, is there a way to get this authorization? How do I send the resquest with this cookie. @CBroe

Comment: You probably will have to "visit" `https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/ranking` first with your scraper tool, to get the cookie value - and then send it with the next request to the actual API endpoit.

Comment: I did it with requests session and session.cookies.get_dict and it return empty {}.